# stuck after first reboot with UEFI clean install of Windows 10

Tags: boot, partitioning, installation, windows-10, uefi

Install with media from MS MCT Win10pro x64 from a SD-Card slot.
Did a fresh GPT partitioning of 128 GB SSD as from Win10´s choice.
after the first reboot it stucks at the blue windows logo, but before Windows is actually booting (so not safe mode/logging of drivers).

Now the strange thing: When I plug in a USB stick or SD card the installed Windows 10 boots again! not every time but most times.
what the heck??
Any idea? I'm quite lost.

*(I must admit that the device is a MBA 2011 which isn't supported by Apple.)*

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit

Windows-Start-Manager
---------------------
Bezeichner              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {a569a3fb-603c-11e5-9ef2-8784ae1558dd}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 0

Windows-Startladeprogramm
-------------------------
Bezeichner              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {a569a3fb-603c-11e5-9ef2-8784ae1558dd}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard

--------------------------------

DISKPART> list disk

  Datenträger ###  Status         Größe    Frei     Dyn  GPT
  ---------------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
* Datenträger 0    Online          113 GB      0 B        *
  Datenträger 1    Online           14 GB      0 B

DISKPART> list part

  Partition ###  Typ               Größe    Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Wiederherstellun   450 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    System             100 MB   451 MB
  Partition 3    Reserviert          16 MB   551 MB
  Partition 4    Primär             112 GB   567 MB

DISKPART> list vol

  Volume ###  Bst  Bezeichnung  DS     Typ         Größe    Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     C   MacbookC     NTFS   Partition    112 GB  Fehlerfre  Startpar
  Volume 1         Wiederherst  NTFS   Partition    450 MB  Fehlerfre  Versteck
  Volume 2                      FAT32  Partition    100 MB  Fehlerfre  System
  Volume 3     D                       Wechselmed      0 B  Kein Medi
```

Comment: I felt very "down", but it was a typo :) http://superuser.com/revisions/976141/1

Answer (score 0):

I just forced Bootcamp Setup to run though the video driver does not work (need to RDP and use generic driver).

And the Boot partition selection of that tool **did it make work.**
I have no clue why, because BCD and Partitions were unmodified, I double checked that. It seems that this Apple tool was able to modify a pointer to the right partition inside the UEFI firmware that was unaccessible before??!

please share similar experiences before I close the question.
thanks.

Comment: note: the problem came back, when I deactivate the built in SD card reader (while debugging the rest of the system)